# Grub boot windows if hibernated

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, hibernate

Is there any way to boot Windows **automatically** if it is hibernated in Grub?

I mean is there any way to **force** the user to boot the hibernated Windows without any choices?

Comment: @nikamanish I don't even want to give the user a choice. I want to *force* booting Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**grub-customizer**](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-grub-customizer-ubuntu-16-04-lts/) We can customize grub. For you, you can select option automatically boot last booted OS.

Comment: The answer you gave is correct... but you should've marked it as duplicate

Comment: I don't even want to give the user a choice. I want to *force* booting Windows.

Comment: just change the "default entry" in grub customizer to windows and you are good to go!!